# How to add numbers to a dial?

Tags: modeling, text-object

I'm trying to make numbers fit on a television dial like this:

[image]

But I'm having difficulty getting the numbers to align perfectly (i.e. not having the number 20 spread out but close together).  I've been trying to follow this demonstration [making of a dial in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwhgMjysWMI&t=63s) but I just can't get the numbers to align properly with the vertices of the circle.

This is what I am working with:

[image]

Does anyone know of a simple way to do this?

Here is the .blend
[image]

**This is the .blend for LukeD**

[image]

Comment: *Totally offtopic.* Normals on your mesh are inverted, go to Edit Mode and recalculate them. Selected object (dial) seems to be created by joining two meshes. You will need to separately Flip Normals.

Comment: You could also create those numbers with texture, it would significantly lower the polycount while maybe the loss of the quality won't be that big. You will really want numbers to be as meshes if you intend them to bulge from the dial circle (like extruded once on the surface).

Comment: @LukeD you're totally right...my normals were so messed.  Recalculated and their great.  Thanks for pointing that out...much appreciated!

Comment: @MrZak Yeah I thought about UV unwrapping the mesh and adding the numbers as a texture, but I do want them to bulge a little bit for that added realism.  But good suggestion though.

Comment: @lakerice even if you use a texture you can have them "bulge a little" if you use the texture for color and bump (or displacement).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fastest way (if a little inacurate) is probably using a single text object, with every single dial text as a word (separated by a space character)

Add a *Curve* modifier to said text object, and point it to a Bezier Curve Circle matching the desired dial radius.

Adjust the vertical positioning of text as desired, the control its radial positioning through the *Word Spacing* property.

[image]

For more precise positioning you are probably better off making each dial text a separate text object, then manually place it radially by using the 3D cursor positioned at the dial center as rotation pivot.

You may also use an [arrayed plane, then have numbers placed inside a single group/collection used as particle system](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198519), this also allows non rotated text.

Comment: Sorry one more follow up question...how can I get them to stick to the dial after?  I tried using the shrinkwrap modifier but it really warped the numbers.

Comment: *Shrinkwrap* would probably be the best way, make sure you tick the option *Apply modifier on spline'points rather than filled surfaces* on the modifier header, so you can bevel the spline

Comment: Hm strange it doesn't show that option in my version...just "adjust edit cage to modifier result"

Answer (score 8):

You may do it using a ***Simple Deform (Bend) modifier*** although it'll deform the text a bit.
[image]

Add a *text* and separate every letter by a space character. Convert it to the mesh with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
[image]

Being in *Object Mode* add a ***Simple Deform modifier*** and set its type to ***Bend***. 
[image]

Change the *Deform* angle value like you need. 
[image]

***NOTE:*** You may do the similar operation being in *Edit Mode* with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut.

Comment: Thanks I tried it but yeah it's a little deformed for the double digit numbers.  Interesting method though!

Answer (score 6):

### Overview:

[image: Overview]

1. You need **Circle** with the same number of vertices as the number of... numbers.
2. Numbers should be individual objects; with **Origin to Center of Mass** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>); grouped with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
3. **Particle System** added to the **Circle** should have same number as above. Also check **Emit From Verts**; uncheck **Random**; select your **Group** and change **Size** a little bit. Sometimes only this will position numbers correctly.

### Blend file:

[image]

### Edit:

It was hard to catch whats going on, but after all it was just a simple difference. I was making it in **Top View** and you've rotated **Circle** to view it from **Front View**.

To get rid of **Circle** rotation problem you can just enable **Rotation** and switch **Initial Orientation** to **Normal-Tangent**.

[image: eit]

Now you can rotate it as you want.

> If in any case you'll want to apply Scale to the Circle keep in mind
>   that you'll need to set Phase to 0.5. It will rotate numbers 90
>   degrees. But it's just 'in case'.

Comment: Dang I tried to use this method but it just won't work for some reason.  I'll study your .blend more

Comment: Try to make it in a new file. Maybe there is something wrong in your main file as inverted normals for example. This is by far most precise method here, so give it a try.

Comment: Still can't get it to work...sorry for the trouble.  I've attached the .blend from scratch for you in the original question if you want to tell me where I went wrong.  Definitely want to nail this method.

Comment: @lakerice check my edit, now everything should be perfect :) Also change size to something higher value to see numbers better.