# Rotate text with curve modifier without spiraling

Tags: bezier-curves, text-object

I'm working through [this watch creation tutorial](http://blendermesh.dasya.com/creating-a-fancy-watch-in-blender), and I have text with a curve modifier added to it, using a bezier circle as the targeted object.  The problem I'm having is that when I attempt to rotate the numbers into correct position, regardless of whether I rotate either the bezier circle or the text object, the text begins to spiral.  Is there a way to rotate without the spiral happening?

Comment: Also possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80298/how-to-add-numbers-to-a-dial/80300#80300

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The transformation axis in the screenshot is X.
If you rotate your text, the X values of the text are different and it spirals.

Solution:
Translate the text only on the X axis (G-key followed by X-key). This way the text moves along the circle.